# Plot polygon with centroid located exterior/outside of polygon

Tags: python, gis, polygon, centroid

How do I plot a polygon with the centroid located outside of the polygon in Python?

Comment: the same way as you plot one with the centroid inside the polygon? what library are you using?

Comment: Either matplotlib or shapely

Comment: I’ve looked through many online resources and I can’t seem to find a way to plot a plot a polygon with the centroid located outside. So far I have only found ways to plot a polygon with the centroid located on the inside.

Comment: Normally, no one cares where the centroid is so just plot the polygon as usual

Answer (score 2):

No idea how to in python, but I guess the assumption is, that polygon has to be convex. Not necessary. Below an illustration in R with standard st_centroid (as in Postgis or `sf`).

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.2, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
pl1 = list(rbind(c(0,0), c(1,0), c(0.12,0.12), c(0,1), c(0,0)))
polygon <- st_polygon(x = pl1)
plot(polygon)
pt <- st_centroid(polygon)
plot(pt, pch = 18, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>